# Insert current date/time in HTTP POST

Tags: html, date, http, time

I am an embedded developer and I am hosting a form web page on an embedded system.  The user fills out the form then sends a message to the embedded system.  I can create whatever name and value fields I want and they all get sent to the embedded system.  Now I need to stick in the current date/time from the PC.

I've read through everything I can find, but I feel like the answers are missing things a web developer would take for granted.  For example, I know what a JS is and basically how to create one.  What I don't know is how to create a field for date/time that is filled out automatically then sent to the embedded side.

There's a button to click to send the form defined as:

```
<input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="sm" value="Send Configuration Message"></div>
```

The form is defined as:

```
<form method="post" action="/config/index.htm" onsubmit="btn=document.getElementById('btnSubmit'); btn.value='(please wait)'; btn.disabled = true;" style="width: 1000px">
```

So it seems that I need to do something else onsubmit to append the time, possibly in a new name/value field.

I've tried a bunch of examples using JS, PHP and other methods, but the bottom line is when the form is received on my embedded side there is no date/time.

Does anyone have a *simple* answer that a know-nothing like me can easily implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is not nice-looking but the implementation might be easy for you.
Let's add a hidden input field and fill it in the moment of submitting the form.

1. New input field

`<input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="sm" value="Send Configuration Message">
<input  id='inputTime' name='time' type='hidden'> //the field is hidden`

2. Edit form onsubmit parameter

`<form method="post" action="/config/index.htm" onsubmit=" 
document.getElementById('inputTime').value=new Date().toJSON().slice(0,16);btn=document.getElementById('btnSubmit'); btn.value='(please wait)'; btn.disabled = true;" style="width: 1000px">`

Once again, it's messy but you can copy-paste it.
If you want to try it more, try this https://jsfiddle.net/ygtq8s8h/ (where I added an alert so that you see what is being sent.)

Comment: Thanks Edvard.  I tried something very similar to that.  I'll try this in the morning. -- Dave

Comment: Don't forget to accept my answer if this works for you ;)

Comment: Hi Edvard, Couple of questions.  I added your new input, but prior to the <form method=.  Is this OK.  Second question is, how do I get the new time value sent down with the rest of the form?  Still investigating...

Comment: Moved the new input to the bottom, inside my form.  Apparently not getting a name field of 'time' on my embedded side.

Comment: You put the input well back inside the form. (I wrote the input before the form, adopting to you when asking the question, you wrote the input before the form.) Did you try the jsfiddle I posted? Does alert dialog appear when you click "Send conf message" button in the fiddle?
If not, would you please add your whole form to that fiddle and paste the link here? I may take a look and see where you did a typo..

Comment: Hi Edvard, Thanks again for your help.  I really appreciate it.  OK, I took your fiddle and used it for my form.  I only changed 'inputTime' to 'date' so that the field name matched my embedded side.  And yes, I do get the alert with the time shown (though it appears to be UTC and I want localtime).  But when I submit, I do get the form on the embedded side but I still do not get a field on my embedded side with the name field 'date'.  Dave

Comment: The date seems to be correctly sent to the embedded side. Maybe you've got problem on the embedded side. You may create a fiddle (or post somewhere) the code on the embedded side so that we find the typo.

Concerning date format, you may want to study further the date object https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Sigh.  This is way difficult for me since it's not my field.

Comment: My "normal" form has 13 fields, plus I need to add date/time. To test your suggestion, I removed all 13 fields from a basic form then used your fiddle with the change to "date" without changing the embedded side since it would look for "date" and parse appropriately. What I found was "date" was saved as the value for the first field (which has a name of "umail"). Nowhere do I see the actual date string itself.  The actual form hosting on the embedded side is example code from a chip vendor. They de-reference the raw WiFi packet a few times so I have no visibility (yet) to see what's inside.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't think I am able to debug it for you without seeing the code.
(If you changed inputTime to 'date', do not forget to change rather name='time' to name='date'. Because name parameter is send through POST request; parameter id is not send through POST request.)

Comment: sorry.  <p>testing</p>
<form method="post" action="/config/index.htm" onsubmit=" 
alert(document.getElementById('date').value=new x.toString(Date());btn=document.getElementById('btnSubmit'); btn.value='(please wait)'; btn.disabled = true;" style="width: 1000px">

<input  id='date' name='date' type='hidden'>
<input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="sm" value="Send Configuration Message">
</form>

Comment: One of the problem may be the variable 'x'. I don't know where you've taken it from. In my code, there is "new Date().toJSON().slice(0,16)", in your code, there is "new x.toString(Date());" What should it do?

Comment: I'm so addled since I've tried about 100 different things. I went back to my real form, but adding your code:  <form method="post" action="/config/index.htm" onsubmit=document.getElementById('date').value=new Date().toJSON().slice(0,16));"btn=document.getElementById('btnSubmit'); btn.value='(please wait)'; btn.disabled = true;" style="width: 1000px">  and <input  id='date' name='date' value="020516 10:06:00" type='hidden'>  Note the one difference is I've stuck in a default value for 'date'. My real form has 13 fields.  All fields are populated correctly.  'date' contains the default value.

Comment: I should say when I POST my form, all fields on the embedded side contain the correct values, with 'date' containing the default value of "020516 10:06:00".  That makes it appear that the value=new Date().toJSON().slice(0,16)); is not updating the 'date' field with the new value.

Comment: I tried moving <input id='date' name='date' value="020516 10:06:00" type='hidden'> outside of the form and I didn't get anything on the embedded side.

Comment: Moving it out will make things worse. When you posted my code back Feb 5 at 18:14, I see another typo at first sight: onsubmit=document.getElementById
In my original post, there is " sign just before document. If you tried to tweak it up in jsfiddle, you wouldn't have to try 100 different things. If you don't know the language well, you'll make more unnecessary errors. Please try to use jsfiddle so that I can help you because I am not able to debug it for you without seeing the code. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay.  Yes, autocomplete caused me to insert typos, but that wasn't the problem.  For some reason, the "onsubmit" solution didn't work.  But I was able to make it work by inserting this into my button:  onclick="document.getElementById('date').value = Date()".  I went back to onsubmit, made sure no typos, and it still didn't work.  So I've settled on the onclick solution so I can move on.  I don't know why onsubmit didn't work.  Incompatible with my browser (Chrome)???  Order of precedence for onsubmit???  Dunno  Edvard, I really appreciate the time.  THANKS!!!

Comment: That's why we are here. +1 if it works and accept if you like.